# Why the xrange function in the library code still works?

Tags: python, scipy, google-colaboratory, xrange

I'm running python code on the Google Colab with Python3 kernel. I found that in the `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` source code (using `??`), it uses `xrange` somewhere as

```
        for i in xrange(0, mA):
            for j in xrange(0, mB):
                dm[i, j] = metric(XA[i], XB[j], **kwargs)
```

And I try to mimic the code in the colab notebook myself, however it says there is no `xrange` function. After some search, I realize that `xrange` function is no more supported in python3.

So my question is, why the `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` still works while the `xrange` is already abandoned in python3? Doesn't it need a update?

Comment: What version of scipy? I couldnt find any reference to xrange in the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.0/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2617-L2960)

Comment: @Sayse - [`scipy 1.4.1`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L2764). It's a custom [`xrange`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L119) `from scipy._lib.six import xrange` in fact python3 builtin [`range`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/_lib/six.py#L85).